# User control child control properties

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties

This is probably very simple to do, but I'm having a brain fart (being sleep deprived will do that to you).

I've got a WPF User Control and I want to expose a property (as read only) of one of its child controls to the outside world so I can bind to it.

Whats the best way?

---

I think I should expand on this, as it may be more fiddly than I gave an impression of. I've got a grid with a column in it of width "*". When its contents have been loaded I want to be able to get the ActualWidth of the column and pass that out of the usercontrol as a read only property (so I can bind another control to the same value and have it match the size).

I'm not sure how to set up a dependency property to do this properly.